# How to register for ACTION_VIEW Intent on Android? Why doesn't my QApplication receive QEvent::FileOpen events?

Tags: android, qt, qt5, qevent, qapplication

I am trying to register a QtQuick Android application to open a certain class of files and handle them.

From what I gather, when a file is opened with a `QApplication` it results in a [`QEvent::FileOpen`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html) being fired.

The strongest (if inconclusive) evidence for this I have is [this](http://developer.telldus.com/changeset/8eaeefd21522b44e7a0fa2d8a4a5868f6bda3a34/Telldus%20Live!%20mobile) commit found in a production system, plus a number of [blog posts](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/9973-QFileOpenEvent-on-Gnome) and Google results.

So, I first create a [new empty QtQuick project](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/commit/e29b97f31b3c9c04cdbb237d74f29a946d8dc066).

I [then write an EventFilter](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/commit/7a581a12bc3427bdccd71e498dc524cc93ec6d13), like this:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>

#include <QFileOpenEvent>

class MyEventFilter : public QObject {
  public:
  MyEventFilter();
  virtual ~MyEventFilter();
protected:
  virtual bool eventFilter(QObject* object,QEvent* event);
};
```

---

```
#include "myeventfilter.h"

MyEventFilter::MyEventFilter() : QObject () {}
MyEventFilter::~MyEventFilter() {}
bool MyEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject* object,QEvent* e) {
  qDebug() << "Received" << e->type();
  if (e->type() == QEvent::FileOpen) {
      QFile file(static_cast<QFileOpenEvent *>(e)->file());
      qDebug() << "File to open:" << file.fileName();
      // This is where I would do stuff
      return true;
  } else {
      return QObject::eventFilter(object,e);
  }
}
```

I then [register it](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/commit/ab74bb96a048aa4d496b4751764cef6062a800fe) and [edit my manifest accordingly](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/commit/2bc1786ec9ea2031244527adb9eb465a11107830), by adding

```
        <intent-filter android:label="Foo File" android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="success"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.foo"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

At this point, I launch my application in the Android emulator.

When I open a `.foo` file from ES File Explorer in my AVD with Nexus 5, API 22, my application **is *indeed* brought in the foreground**, but ***no* `FileOpen` events** are logged.

If I set up a **breakpoint** inside my filter method I don't seem to be hitting it.

This puzzles me.

I tried the alternate approach by extending `QApplication` and overloading `event(QEvent *)` with pretty much the same results (no hits).

What could I be doing wrong?

---

*Please find the complete repository for this MWE [here](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question after perusing [Bogdan's tutorials](https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf) and receiving some invaluable help from `#qt` on Freenode.

It looks like opening a file in Android does *not*, in fact, result in a `QEvent::FileOpen`, which is useful only on systems with a window manager.

Instead, one has to [subclass `QtActivity` and override `onIntent`](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/commit/3d1c3f76e80601de4db14914bb303b3fc2164c1e) in Java, then [call an appropriate C++ method](https://github.com/tobiatesan/android_intents_qt/commit/98b8fb92db9d1b8f9912ea4803a4bf9d4f77f8e1) with JNI:

```
package com.foo;

import android.content.Intent;

import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity;

class Bar
{
    public static native void openUri(String uri);
    // Notice the 'native' keyword
}

public class MyActivity extends QtActivity {
    public void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
        if (i.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
            Bar.openUri(i.getData().toString());
        }
        super.onNewIntent(i);
    }
}
```

---

```
class URIHandler : public QObject {
public:
    void openUri(QString uri) {
        qDebug() << "Open URI" << uri;
    }
}
```

---

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
  Java_com_foo_Bar_openUri(JNIEnv *env,
                                                    jobject obj,
                                                    jstring uri)
{
    jboolean isCopy;
    isCopy = false;
    const char* utf = env->GetStringUTFChars(uri, &isCopy);
    handler.openUri(QString(utf));
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(uri, utf);

}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

---

Note that there are [some tricky subtleties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/design.html) with JNI method names.

You can find the updated, working version of this example [here](https://github.com/tobiatesan/qevent_test/).

Comment: Great it works. But how can I read content of file? QFile::readAll() throw error device not open.

Comment: @LiborB. I can't for the life of me remember. I'll see if I can dig up this code in the next days and try to answer you.